# Порт стандартного генератора случайных чисел с Java на C++

Tags: java, c++, случайные-числа

Изучаю C++. До этого изучал Java. В целях обучения портирую часть стандартного класса java.util.Random на C++.

```
public class Random {

    private long seed;
    private long multiplier;
    private long addend;
    private long mask;
    private final double DOUBLE_UNIT;

    public Random(long seed) {
        this.seed = seed;
        multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
        addend = 0xBL;
        mask = (1L << 48) - 1;
        DOUBLE_UNIT = 0x1.0p-53;
    }

    public double nextValue() {
        return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
    }

    private int next(int bits) {
        long nextSeed = (seed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
        seed = nextSeed;
        return (int)(nextSeed >>> (48 - bits));
    }

}
```

соответствующий класс C++:

```
class Random {

private:
    long long seed;
    long long multiplier;
    long long addend;
    long long mask;
    const double DOUBLE_UNIT = 0x1.0p-53;

    int next(int bits) {
        long long nextSeed = (seed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
        seed = nextSeed;
        return (int)(nextSeed >> (48 - bits));
    }

public:
    Random(long long seed):seed(seed) {
        multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DLL;
        addend = 0xBLL;
        mask = (1LL << 48) - 1;
    }

    double nextValue() {
        return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
    }

};
```

**Что не получается:** класс Java, как и надо, выдает результат в диапазоне от 0 до 1. класс C++ выдает результат выходящий за этот диапазон. При создании объектов этих классов им передаются одинаковые ключи.

**Как я пытался решить проблему:** на сколько я могу судить - типы данных переменных(целое или вещественное) и их разрядность я подобрал одинаковые для java и c++ классов; оператор java >>> и оператор C++ >> имеют одинаковое поведение.

**Какие инструменты использовал:** Для java - JDK11, класс java.util.Random брался из этой версии. Для c++ - компилировал с помощью g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0, используя команду g++ main.cpp -o main.exe.

**Вопрос:** Скажите пожалуйста - где я ошибся при портировании java класса в C++? В чем причина разного поведения?

Comment: Послушайте, не открывайте Америку через форточку... Уж где-где, но в C++ случайные числа реализованы весьма тщательно и надежно...

Comment: Да, тщательно и надежно. И реализованы лучше, чем это могу на данный момент сделать я. Но как я писал - это в целях обучения. Я просматривал код ГПСЧ реализованных на C++. Но понял плохо. Поэтому решил пощупать тему на практике, на каком-нибудь очень простом примере. Поскольку более-менее знаю Java, решил "подобраться к пониманию" через копирование и сравнение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

возможно дело в том, что один `long` не заменен на `long long`

```cpp
return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
```

используйте для надежности тип `int64_t`